# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer won't work in iOS 13 simulator

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11

The `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` won't call its action selector when I deploy on the **iOS 13** simulator. The same code works for **iOS 12** simulator devices and on real iOS 13 hardware.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let edgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenEdgeSwiped))
    edgePan.edges = .left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(edgePan)
}

@objc func screenEdgeSwiped(_ recognizer: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
  if recognizer.state == .recognized {
    print("swipe gesture recognized ✔︎")
  }
}
```

I've created a [small sample project](https://github.com/BigDada1/ScreenEdgePanGestureDemo). Swiping in the iOS 12 simulator works. In the iOS 13 simulator the selector method `screenEdgeSwiped` won't be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enabling `Window > Show Device Bezels` for the iOS Simulator. I filed a bug with Apple regarding this feature not working as it did previously (FB7253111) but they said this was an intentional change.

Comment: Enabling of Device Bezels doesn't fix it for me :(

Comment: Ah I should swipe from the bezel edge, not from the screen edge! Aaaah!